# Multiselect Person column - concatenate multiple @currentFeild values for each record's txtContent

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, json

I have a multiselect person column, and need each record not just to display the users name, but also their job title in brackets, preferably deliniated by a new line.

So far, I have the following JSON:

*{
"elmType": "div",

"children":[

{"elmType": "div",

"forEach": "person in @currentField",

"txtContent":  "=@currentField.title + ' (' + @currentField.jobTitle + ')'"

}
]

}*

My outputs are containing the name and title of all entries and in the wrong order, i.e.

"John Doe; Jane Doe (John Does jobTitle; Jane Does jobTitle)"

Im trying to get it to output:

"John Doe (John Does jobTitle); Jane  Doe (Jane Does jobTitle)

At first it was returning nothing until i figured out that forEach doesnt work on the root. But now I cant figure out where im going wrong in the formatting....please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `forEach` you are setting up an iterator. In your case you've called it `person` so you would need to access individual values using that as the internal column name. So your format should work by adjusting it like so:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "display": "flex",
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "forEach": "person in @currentField",
      "txtContent": "=[$person.title] + ' (' + [$person.jobTitle] + ')'"
    }
  ]
}
```

I also added some style information to the root div to ensure that each of the people end up on a new line.

Comment: Thank you theChrisKent, makes total sense!